# Is following Relation from $X$ to $Y$ is a Relation or not?

Tags: relations

$$X=\{1,2,3,4,5\} \text{ and } Y=\{1,3,5,7,9\}$$

$$R=\{(x,y)\mid y=2+x,x\in X, y\in Y\}$$

my textbook says it is a relation from $X$ to $Y$. But for $x=2$, $y=4$ but $4$ is not in $Y$.
How is that possible?

Comment: Sounds like a typo; perhaps they intended a relation of $y = 2x - 1$.

Comment: yes it is..thanks

Answer (score 1):

Any relation between $X$ and $Y$ is **a subset of** $X\times Y$, so $R$ qualifies.

By the way, use $\in$ instead of $\epsilon$.

Comment: R is not subset of X \times Y...so its clear it is typo

Comment: @T. Noor It says that $x\in X, y\in Y$

Comment: sir, there is (2,4) in R which is not in X\times Y

Comment: @I'm interpreting $,$ as $\land$, but it depends on the context.